# NSURL fileURLWithPath where NSString has a space

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsurl

I've looked at quite a few of the related questions and cannot find a similar problem or a solution so my apologies if there is a duplicate out there somewhere.

Anyway, I'm trying to generate a file's NSURL to use with an NSXMLDocument. I have the following components:

```
const NSString * PROJECT_DIR = @"~/SP\\ BB/";
const NSString * STRINGS_FILE = @"Localizable.strings";
```

and construct the URL like so:

```
NSURL * stringsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",PROJECT_DIR,STRINGS_FILE] stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
```

however, the resulting path in the NSURL is:
file://localhost/Users/timothyborrowdale/SP2B/Localizable.strings

I have tried changing the PROJECT_DIR to

```
@"~/SP BB/"
@"~/SP\\\\ BB/" (changes to SP엀2B)
@"~/SP%20BB/"
@"~/SP\%20BB/"
```

with the same problem. I also tried typing out the file url completely and using `[NSURL URLWithString:]`

I have also tried using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` with both NSUTF8Encoding and NSASCCIEncoding and these have the same issue.

The NSString displays properly before being passed to NSURL or `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` but has the problem once outputted from either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *fnam = [@"Localizable" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"strings"];
NSArray *parts = [NSArray arrayWithPathComponents:@"~", @"SP BB", fnam, (void *)nil];
NSString *path = [[NSString pathWithComponents:parts] stringByStandardizingPath];
NSURL *furl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

Foundation has a host of platform-independent, path-related methods. Prefer those over hard-coding path extension separators (often ".") and path component separators (often "/" or "\").

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work, the path is created fine, but the url has the same problem

Comment: How did you determine that? Does reading in the file using `+[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` work? If not, what error does it give?

Comment: That works actually. Perhaps it's not the path that's at fault. I'll try getting the err from the XMLDocument init.

Answer (score 0):

Try abandoning `stringWithFormat:` (never the right answer for stapling paths together) and `stringByExpandingTildeInPath` and using `NSHomeDirectory()` and `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` instead.

> - @"~/SP\\ BB/" (changes to SP엀2B)

How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: That hasn't worked either. Again the initial NSString is fine, but not the url. Regarding that line, I just copied the text from the console.

Comment: Septih: What did you print to the Console, and how did you print it?

Comment: This code is part of a unit test, so I'm hacking around with my STAssertTrue(condition,format,...) lines to see what's going on, so really the line is coming from the build results console when the build fails. The actual item printed is the NSURL description.